# Authentication using Nuxt.js and Firebase middleware

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

- I have a Nuxt Js 3 + Firebase project. In this project, login is required to access the admin panel.
- The code sections I wrote below are working properly.

However, as you can see in the Gif, when I go to the /admin/dashboard page without logging in, the page comes for a few seconds, that is, it renders and sends it to the login page.

**What I want** is to first check if you are logged in, if you are not logged in, it does not go to /admin/dashboard and stays on the login page.

[image: Problem Gif]

```
//middleware/isAuth.js

import { auth } from "~~/firebase/config";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  await auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user == null && to.name != "admin") {
      return await navigateTo("/admin");
    } else if (user && to.name == "admin") {
      return navigateTo("/admin/dashboard");
    } else if (user && to.name != "admin") {
      return navigateTo(from.fullPath);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Stop rendering it on server side.

Comment: And do not use `onAuthStateChanges()` inside middleware! You will have memory leaks.

Comment: And all your users are admins? Why you have no any claims in user auth token?

Comment: Where should I use onAuthStateChanged()?

This is the admin panel, only administrators can log in from here, so I didn't set a control.

 Going to the "/" page, they will see the regular blog page.

Comment: If you enable login, you are enabling sign in. Anyone who know your page can create account and become an admin?

Comment: no, anyone who knows the page cannot open an account and become an administrator. Currently there is only one administrator.

Comment: `onAuthStateChange()` is a listener, it returns unsubscription that you should unsubscribe. Using it in global middleware will make new listeners every time you navigate somewhere.

Comment: What would you suggest I use for this?

Comment: If you enable login in authentication, you're enabling sign in with it. If someone knows your page exists and know how firebase works can just sign in and become an admin.

Comment: All I can suggest to you is to learn more about how authentication works and everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251986/discussion-between-serdar-goleli-and-mises).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem without using middleware with a little trick

```
// layouts/admin/default.vue
<template>
   <div v-if="loading">loading</div>
   <div v-else>
   ....
   </div>
<template>
<script setup>
  import { useAuthStore } from "~~/stores/authStore";
  import { auth } from "@/firebase/config";

  const currentUser = ref(false);
  const loading = ref(true);
  const router = useRouter();
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
    loading.value = true;
    currentUser.value = await auth.currentUser;
    if (currentUser.value) {
      await authStore.setCurrentUser(currentUser.value);
      router.push("/admin/dashboard");
    } else {
      router.push("/admin");
    }
    loading.value = false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Memory leaks...... You can change layouts and every time you change layout to admin layout you will initiate `onAuthStateChanges()` listener. This listener won't go away, it will work all time until user lave browser tab, so you might end up with 30 listeners triggering function inside `onAuthStateChanges()`.

Comment: But it's better than middleware. XD Then you was initiating listener every time user was changing route. Best place for `onAuthStateChange()` is in plugin or `app.vue` file.

Comment: Actually, I am creating a blog page for myself here. When I go to the "/admin" page, I want to add, update or delete content by logging in with the admin user I created before.

I want it to be active in every way until I log out.

so I am using onAuthStateChanges . What should I use instead?

I need to listen for this admin user so I was using onAuthStateChanges.